# React props received by component but not updating in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So this is an interesting one. Here is a snippet of the code. This is a purely functional component and I am passing an object we're going to call someData via props.

BASICINFO BEFORE RETURN gets logged the first time the component renders with the default someData object. 'BASICINFO AFTER RETURN then gets logged again with the default someData object. When the parent component's state updates, BASICINFO BEFORE RETURN logs showing the updated data, but I don't get the log BASICINFO AFTER RETURN showing the updated props as I'd expect. It's as if it's unaware of the props update. Does anybody know what causes this?

```
export function MyComponent({someData}: MyComponentProps) {
  console.log('BASICINFO BEFORE RETURN', someData.basicInfo);
  return (
    <Flex>
      {console.log('BASICINFO AFTER RETURN', someData.basicInfo)}
      <Box>
        <p>
          {someData.basicInfo.personalSummary}
        </p>
      </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah turns out I was mutating state. I was dealing with objects nested a few levels deep. Ended up flattening state and just saving what I really needed. Should have done that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the component isn't re-rendering because none of the displayed data is actually different? ie: if basicInfo.personalSummary changes, does the component re-render?

If the displayed data is changing and it isn't re-rendering, are you sure the state isn't being mutated?